# Showing that a relation on elements of a group is an equivalence relation

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ to be group and $A,B<G$. Let $x,y \in G$. we define $x \sim y$ to be $y=a\ast x \ast b$ for $a\in A$ and $b \in B$. I want to prove that $x \sim y$ is an equivalence relation.

I should prove:

1) $x=a*x*b$

2) if $y=a*x*b$, then $x=a*y*b$

3) if $y=a*x*b$ and $z=a*y*b$, then $z=a*x*b$ ( is that right ? )

any ideas ?

Comment: Your second and third statement are not quite right. You are treating the $a, b$ as fixed, when in fact they can change. The equivalence relation stipulates $x \sim y$ means $y = axb$ for some $a \in A, b \in B$. In other words, $x \sim y$ means $y = a_{1}xb_{1}$, and $y \sim x$ means $x = a_{2}yb_{2}$, but $a_{1}$ does not have to equal $a_{2}$ and $b_{1}$ does not have to equal $b_{2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1) Since $A, B$ are subgroups, $e \in A$ and $e \in B$

2) Suppose $y = axb$. Then $x = a^{-1}yb^{-1}$. What do you know about subgroups?

3) Suppose $y = a_{1}xb_{1}$ and $z = a_{2}yb_{2}$. Then $z=a_{1}a_{2}xb_{1}b_{2}$. Again, what do you know about subgroups?

Comment: 1)since A,B are subgroups , x = e * x * e = x

Comment: @NizarHalloun: yes, that's the first one. How about the other two?

Comment: 2) a−1 b−1 exits becuse A and B are subgroups

Comment: Existence is guaranteed by the fact that $G$ is a group. Not only do they exist, but $a^{-1} \in A$ and $b^{-1} \in B$.

Comment: 3) becuse of a*a∈A and b*b∈B the z exist

Comment: You made the same mistake as the OP in your third sentence.

Comment: Oy, good catch @PedroTamaroff. Thanks, edited.

Comment: @NizarHalloun: the question is not whether $z$ exists. The question is whether $z$ can be written as $axb$ for some $a \in A, b \in B$. As you noted, $A$ a subgroup implies $a_{1}a_{2} \in A$, and likewise $b_{1}b_{2} \in B$.